# How to run a tex file without showing the figures

Tags: floats

I have a large tex file which includes a lot of figures, and I would like to know how much text I have written. (I use texshop to run my files)

Comment: You could try the endfloat package to move the floats to the end.

Comment: I think many LaTeX editors has some kind of statistics, like word count, for the document. You can use this to have an idea.

Answer (score 3):

The `[draft]` option on `\usepackage{graphicx}` or `\documentclass` suppresses image inclusion.

`draft` does leave a box with the image name, you coudl also do

```
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}
```

which will redefine `\includegraphics` to do nothing other than gobble its arguments.

Comment: Thank you, but I have just tried this, and I don't have figures, instead, I have empty boxes.

Comment: I would like, in fact, have only text in the end and totally omit figures.

Comment: What would you then recommend?

Comment: @Dana by figure do you mean just the image or you want to lose captions as well?

Comment: You may define a variable, and redefine the figure environment based on that variable to show/omit figures. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Dana perhaps you want `\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}` so that the command does nothing?